# Sharepoint 2007 explorer view not working and Connect to Outlook menu not displaying

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, synchronization, windows-explorer

We have a SharePoint 2007 installation and I am running on a Windows 7 machine with Outlook 2010 and Internet explorer 11.

When I am in the "Shared Documents" the "Connect to Outlook" menu item was not displayed and selecting the "explorer view" from the view menu on the right would give me the following error:

> your client does not support opening this list with windows explorer

This was true regardless of which browser I used (IE 11, Chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched all over and tried multiple things "WebDAV client", "WebClient Service disabled" etc.
None of the solved the problem.

If I signed myself in on another machine I could see the menus so I suspected it may be the browser version. I tried opening developer tools and switched to IE7 on the emulation page and Voila! it worked!!

I still cant bring myself to say I like IE7 :-)